# Project Manager cancel or move daily stand-up without notice if he has conflicting meetings

Tags: kanban, scheduling, roles, meetings

I've done my homework and searched on the website, and I could find a similar question: [Should we cancel the Daily Stand-Up if we have another meeting during the day?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/20796/should-we-cancel-the-daily-stand-up-if-we-have-another-meeting-during-the-day) but my case is different: my Project Manager is cancelling (or changing the time of the stand-up meeting the same day), not if we have another scrum related meeting, but rather if he (only him) has a call with a client or if he is busy with something else.

I know this is **very** wrong but I'm asking some help from the community to give him constructive feedback, ideally based on sources or articles that I can share with him.

I should also mention that I work in a global digital agency with clients across the world. In other words our PM cannot "afford" to ignore or move a client call as he likes.

Comment: Title says "Scrum Master" but question says "Project Manager." Which is it? Regardless it appears that it might be [Scrum In Name Only](https://youtu.be/a9PY7yEj-Z4?t=30s) (SINO).

Comment: Since this is more about interaction, from a team member role and not a project management type role, this question might be more suitable on the [Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: It's actually project manager. I have changed the title. I also think you are right this could be moved to workplace, although it is also related to how Scrum is adapted to a environment which is not accustomed to it, like Agencies. But I can create a separate question for that.

Comment: Also note that within the [Scrum](https://scrumguides.org) framework, there is no *Project Manager* role. The activities of such a position are often performed by those fulfilling the three roles (Product Owner, Scrum Master, and Development Team) or unnecessary due to the different (product, value-driven, incremental, self-organizing) nature of the framework.

Comment: maybe I should mention it clearly, but I've never said we use Scrum, we rather use Kanban. We work on 2 weeks/4 weeks projects rotation, and anyone in the team can pick up different projects based on availability. It's hard to apply even Kanban..

Comment: The stand-up should be 15 minutes or less. The circumstances under which someone can't set aside 15 minutes per day for a standing meeting and schedule around it are pretty limited. The PM can and should work with the time to find a standing slot s/he can routinely attend.

Comment: I disagree with the close vote. This question seems very much on topic, and appears answerable.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I keep it open to get more answers?

Comment: @giac_man No, he is simply saying that he disagrees with the vote to [close](https://pm.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) your Question as off-topic. It has nothing to do with [accepting an Answer](https://pm.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) (which is what I presume you were asking about).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the most useful advice can actually be found in [the comment](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/20796/should-we-cancel-the-daily-stand-up-if-we-have-another-meeting-during-the-day#comment25869_20796) on your linked Question.

> My manager was absolutely shocked to find out that we still had our stand up when he canceled it (a regular occurrence). My response to him was "The stand up isn't for you. It's for us. Whether you're here or not, we still need to sync up as a team.

The Daily Scrum is not for the Project Manager. It is not for the Product Owner. It is not for the Scrum Master. It is for the *Team*.

You seem to have two problems here. First, your Daily Scrum is being cancelled. Second, your Project Manager is the one cancelling your Daily Scrums.

The first is solved easily - have them anyway. The second will hopefully be fixed once your Scrum Master discovers you are still holding the Daily Scrums. If not, the Scrum framework provides an opportunity to address concerns such as these - the [Sprint Retrospective](https://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html#events-retro).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is short and simple: he or she doesn't have to participate in your daily stand-up.
I know that many Scrum Masters are having a hard time with this because they are afraid that they might miss something (and in my eyes the problem lies another level deeper - missing trust; but that's another story).

I wouldn't have those cancelled daily stand-ups anyway. This is just generating conflict (there's that missing trust again). So if I was you I'd ask him or her straightforward why he or her has the feeling that it's vital that he or she is participating in your daily scrum. Maybe it's enough to make sure it happens and to get some short summary. This will help you both - a classic win-win.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Good point on the trust problem, but I think in this instance it is more due to unclear processes and poor definition of roles responsibilities.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know who "owns" the meeting at your work, but it should be the ScrumMaster (if you have one). If not, I would suggest having one of the developers own the meeting instead of any project manager.

Where I work, I actually "kicked" my manager out of our standup, because we spent the entire time talking to him. He and I have a good relationship, so he readily agreed.

In general, this is an issue that should be explored at retro. Have the entire team discuss the value of the standup to them, and why your PM isn't the most important person in the meeting. Your PM needs to arrange his schedule around everyone else, not vice versa.